# How to fix 'InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.' error in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I'm using Serverless for the first time and have a Lambda inside a VPC that is trying to add a payload to a SQS queue which gives the following error `InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

The error means that the access key is missing or invalid which has me stumped and looking for some help. This is my serverless.yml file.

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: prod
  region: us-east-1
  timeout: 600
  memorySize: 512
  versionFunctions: false

  package:
    excludeDevDependencies: true
    exclude:
      - .git/**
      - .vscode/**
      - .test/**

  # Global Environment variables
  environment:
    ${file(./configs/${self:provider.stage}.yml)}

  # Permissions for all of your functions can be set here
  iamRoleStatements:
    # Gives permission to add to s3 buckets
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:DeleteObject
      Resource: "*"

    # Gives permission to Lambda execution
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
        - lambda:InvokeAsync
      Resource: "*"

    # Gives permission to SQS
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:DeleteMessage
        - sqs:ReceiveMessage
        - sqs:SendMessage
      Resource: "*"

custom:
  region: ${self:provider.region}
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  prefix: ${self:custom.stage}-${self:service}
  sqs-forms-schedule: ${self:custom.prefix}-messages-forms-schedule
  sqs-forms-late: ${self:custom.prefix}-messages-forms-late
  sqs-coc-schedule: ${self:custom.prefix}-messages-coc-schedule
  sqs-certificates-expired: ${self:custom.prefix}-messages-certificates-expired
  s3-coc-storage: ${self:custom.prefix}-storage-coc

  serverless-offline:
    host: '0.0.0.0'

  # Dev
  serverless-offline-sqs-esmq:
    apiVersion: '2012-11-05'
    endpoint: http://sqs:9324
    region: us-east-1
    accessKeyId: root
    secretAccessKey: root

plugins:
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-plugin-aws-alerts
  - serverless-offline-scheduler
  - serverless-offline-sqs-esmq
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  ${file(serverless-dynamic.js)}

resources:
  Resources:
    # Policy to allow for VPC connection
    AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties:
        Description: Creating policy for vpc connection
        Roles:
          - { "Ref": "IamRoleLambdaExecution" }
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
              Resource: "*"

    # SQS Queue to schedule a form for submission
    FormScheduleQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.sqs-forms-schedule}
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
        VisibilityTimeout: 60

    # SQS Queue to schedule a late form for reminder
    FormLateQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.sqs-forms-late}
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
        VisibilityTimeout: 60

    # SQS Queue to schedule a coc for submission
    COCScheduleQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.sqs-coc-schedule}
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
        VisibilityTimeout: 60

    # SQS Queue to schedule an expired certificate for reminder
    CertificatesExpiredQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.sqs-certificates-expired}
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
        VisibilityTimeout: 60
```

I've tried creating new access keys

Here is the code sending to SQS

```
sendToQueue: (message, queue) => {
    const params = {
      QueueUrl: queue,
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message),
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sqs.sendMessage(params, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
  },
```

Comment: Can you share the code which tries to send message to the SQS?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added the SQS code above.

Comment: How do you get the value for `queue`? Do you call GetQueueUrl on `sqs`? After the function is deployed did you check if the role is associated with the function and the role has necessary permissons?